# How do I set up a AWS Cloud9 instance using AWS-CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloud9

I love the idea behind the AWS CDK, but I'm struggling to create a Cloud9 Environment using it.

Every time the below code runs, an "Error while creating Cloud9" error message pops up in the AWS console, followed by "CREATE_FAILED" in the local terminal. First instincts suggest that the way to implement cloud9 is to establish a connection between ec2 and cloud9 – but I don't have any idea how to do that – has anybody successfully used the CDK to create a Cloud9 environment? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

#### AWS Console error message

[image: AWS Console error message]

#### VSCode terminal error message

[image: VSCode terminal error message]

scroll down a little further in ther terminal and this message is at the end:

```
Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named MjwFirstCdkStack failed creation, 
it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Cannot
create the AWS Cloud9 environment. There was a problem connecting to the environment.
```

#### The code used

```
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as ec2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";
import * as cloud9 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloud9";
import { Construct } from "constructs";

export class MjwFirstCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // create a vpc
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "my-vpc-id", {
      natGateways: 1,
      maxAzs: 2,
      ipAddresses: ec2.IpAddresses.cidr("10.0.0.0/16"),
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: "private-subnet-1",
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
          cidrMask: 24,
        },
        {
          name: "public-subnet-1",
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          cidrMask: 24,
        },
      ],
    });

    // create a cloud9 env
    const myCloud9Environment = new cloud9.CfnEnvironmentEC2(
      this,
      "MyCloud9Environment",
      {
        name: "MyCloud9EnvironmentName",
        instanceType: "t2.micro",
        automaticStopTimeMinutes: 60,
        subnetId: vpc.privateSubnets[0].subnetId,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried deploy to the public subnet, refer to the vpc requirements for Cloud9 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html)

note that you need to delete the previously failed deployment before you run "cdk deploy" again. this can be done from the CloudFormation console